# Notepad++ search window not focussed on "Find what:" anymore after pressing "CTRL+F"

Tags: notepad++, search, wine

### Issue Description

On a Wine Notepad++ installation, I am noticing that my Notepad++ installation does not automatically put my caret/cursor in the `Find what:` textbox that is inside the `Find` menu.

### Expected Behaviour

I would expect that if:

1. I put my cursor in an arbitrary place inside a notepad++ file, without selecting anything.
2. Press `Ctrl+f`
3. Type the letter `a`
   That it put's the `a` inside the textbox that is preceded with: `Find what:`. (Such that when I press `enter`, that it starts searching for the next occurence of `a` inside the file that is opened.

### Observed behaviour

The search box is opened after pressing `Ctrl+f`, and when I type: `a` nothing happens.
However, when I press `f`, it briefly (for a fraction of a second) switches (the gray buttons on the right, not the tab in the search window) to: `Mark all`, as captured in the screenshot below:
[image]

### Doubts

The behaviour with the `f` button seems to me like my keyboard has a hanging `ctrl` or `alt` button or something which could result in me thinking I am sending an `f` signal, whereas in reality I might be sending something like `Alt+f`. To exclude this, I registered my keystrokes using `screenkey`, which showed me pressing `ctrl+f` and `a` (without any additional keystrokes).

### Question

It is not clear to me whether this is a bug, whether I am doing something wrong, or whether this is a (new) feature. I would like to ask: How can I ensure the caret is placed automatically in the textbox next to `Find what:` in the search tab after pressing `Ctrl+f`, such that it enters my typing/keystrokes into that textbox when I start typing?

### Software:

Ubuntu:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

Wine:

```
wine-5.0.3 (Ubuntu 5.0.3-3ubuntu2)
```

Notepad-plus-plus:

```
Notepad++ v8.2.1 (64-bit)
```

Note, I installed Notepad++ on a clean Ubuntu installation. Additionally I've removed it and reinstalled it twice without seeing a change in the observed behaviour.

Comment: Is your window manager set to "focus follows mouse" ?

Comment: @BenVoigt Thank you for your question, that may be relevant. I have not yet found how to identify that setting (mostly found how to enable `focus follows mouse`). I will search for that setting in Ubuntu, and if I find it see if it influences the behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Notepad++ is misbehaving, I would normally counsel to uninstall it,
clean up all its folders, then reinstall.

However, as you are using it on Wine, this is not a true Windows environment,
so some Windows applications may malfunction in this environment.
The problem might then not be in Notepad++ itself.

You could try to install the snap version, as explained in
[Notepad++ on Linux is a Reality Thanks to This Snap Application](https://itsfoss.com/notepad-plus-plus-linux/),
as it uses its own embedded version of Wine, so might work better.

If the above doesn't help, you should address the problem to the
Wine forums.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I forgot to mention that I installed it on a clean Ubuntu installation, and that I already uninstalled and re-installed notepad++ using snap. I've edited the question accordingly. So I think this implies you suggest I should address the problem in the Wine forums.

Comment: Yes, that's so. Notepad++ on Windows doesn't have this problem, so the difference must be in the environment, which is Wine.